# How to to use the fact that combining these hypothesis is false in Coq

Tags: coq

Suppose that I have a hypothesis `H1 : a > y` and another hypothesis `H2 : a <= y` in Coq.
I want to use the fact that combining these hypothesis is an instance of `False` so that I get to prove my goal automatically. How should I do it ? (btw, assume that both `a` and `y` are `nat`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose to use `gt_not_le_stt`, you don't need to destruct `a` nor `y`.

```
  Goal forall a y, a > y -> a <= y -> False.
Proof.
 intros a y H H0.
 apply Arith_prebase.gt_not_le_stt in H. 
 exact (H H0).
Qed.
```

Of course, there are a lot of other solutions, depending on the libraries, tactics and lemmas you choose  to use (including the magic `lia`).

Answer (score 2):

There are several quicker solutions.

```ml
Require Import PeanoNat.
Lemma helper : forall a y, a > y -> a <= y -> False.
Proof.
  intros a y H.
  apply Nat.nle_gt. (* Coq guesses the direction of <-> to use *)
  exact H. (* conversion between > and < *)
Qed.
```

For these simple linear inequalities, there is `lia`.

```
Require Import Lia.
Lemma helper' : forall a y, a > y -> a <= y -> False.
Proof. lia. Qed.
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Pierre Casteran, there are multiple possible versions. For the record, here is a simple mathcomp-based one.

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect. 

Lemma helper : forall a y, a > y -> a <= y -> False.
Proof. by  move=> a y ay; rewrite leqNgt ay. Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

whatever .. here's a long-cut...

```
Lemma helper : forall a y, a > y -> a <= y -> False.
Proof.
    intros. destruct y.
    - destruct a.
        + apply Arith_prebase.gt_irrefl_stt in H. destruct H.
        + apply Arith_prebase.le_n_0_eq_stt in H0.
            rewrite H0 in H. apply Arith_prebase.gt_irrefl_stt in H. destruct H.
    - destruct a.
        + apply Arith_prebase.gt_not_le_stt in H. unfold not in H.
            apply H in H0. destruct H0.
        + apply Arith_prebase.gt_not_le_stt in H. unfold not in H.
            apply H in H0. destruct H0.
Qed.
```